# error al pasar el valor de una promise a la vista de pagina eje

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express, promesas, ejs

Tengo problemas para retornar el valor de una base de datos y pasarla a la vista de mi pagina en ejs, ya que mi promise en consola retorna el valor correctamente pero, al tratar de pasar mi objeto "getdato" a mi vista en ejs, aparece en la pagina el mensaje [object promise].
No se si sea limitante de ejs o localhost, soy principiante y les agradeceria mucho el apoyo

*conexion_mysql.js*

```
import mysql from 'promise-mysql';

const database = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'base_de_datos',
    user: 'lista',
    password: 'hfuheduhuehrhr9'
});

const funcionDatabase = ()=>{

    return database;
}

export {funcionDatabase} ;

console.log('el primero funciona');
```

*conexion2.js*

```
 import {funcionDatabase} from './conexion_mysql.js';
    console.log("conexion2 exitosa" ); 

 async function getdatos(req, res){
     let respuesta = [];
    
        const conexionDB = await funcionDatabase();
    const result= await conexionDB.query("SELECT * FROM Elementos");
           
    return result;
    }
    
    export const getdato= getdatos();
```

*rutas.js*

```
import express from 'express';
import {getdato} from '../public/javaScript/conexion2.js';

const rutas= express.Router();


rutas.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('pages/index');
    console.log(`ruta nro 1 conectada correctamente`);
    });

  rutas.get('/cabecera_menu1', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('pages/cabecera_menu1');
    console.log(`ruta nro 2 conectada correctamente`);
    });

     rutas.get('/cabecera_menu2', (req, res)=>{
        res.render('pages/cabecera_menu2');
        console.log('ruta nro 3 conectada correctamente');
        });
    

        rutas.get('/compra/:cantidad_input/:sub_itemId', (req, res)=>{
          let compra_cantidad = req.params.cantidad_input;
          let compra_id = "../../public/imagenes/imagen"+ req.params.sub_itemId +".png";
          console.log("ruta nro 4 conectada correctamente");
          console.log(**getdato**);   <-- ESTE CONSOLE.LOG SI RETORNA EL VALOR DE MI PROMISE CORRECTAMENTE

          //ENVIO DE VARIABLES AL MENU DE COMPRA
          res.render(`pages/menu_compra.ejs`, {compra_cantidad: compra_cantidad , compra_id: **getdato}**);    

//EL VALOR QUE RETORNA "PROMISE {<PENDING>}  ("compra_id: getdato") ^^^ 

            });

            rutas.get('/conexion2', (req, res)=>{
              res.render('pages/conexion2');
              console.log(`ruta nro 5 conectada correctamente`);
              });
          
        
              export default rutas;
```

Como indico el elemento getdato, exportado desde el archivo conexion2.js, imprime correctamente el valor a traves de console.log, pero al igualarlo a la funcion "comprar_id", en la vista de mi pagina menu_compra.ejs devuelve unicamente el valor "[object promise]".

*menu_compra.ejs*

```
 <div class="principal_text"> 
  <%=compra_id%>
 </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se puede pasar una promesa directamente a la vista, tiene que esperar que la promesa se resuelva primero por ejemplo con el método then(). Algo similar a esto:

```
rutas.get('/compra/:cantidad_input/:sub_itemId', (req, res)=>{
  let compra_cantidad = req.params.cantidad_input;
  let compra_id = "../../public/imagenes/imagen"+ req.params.sub_itemId +".png";
  console.log("ruta nro 4 conectada correctamente");

  getdato.then(resultado => {
    console.log(resultado);   // <-- ESTE CONSOLE.LOG IMPRIMIRÁ EL RESULTADO DE LA PROMESA UNA VEZ QUE SE RESUELVA
    //ENVIO DE VARIABLES AL MENU DE COMPRA
    res.render(`pages/menu_compra.ejs`, {compra_cantidad: compra_cantidad , compra_id: resultado});
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
});
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, había probado esa forma pero no la escribí correctamente y me arrojaba error, gracias por la ayuda!